# Nested Scrolling not working with viewpager inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2, nestedscrollview

I am using nesterdscrollview and inside a viewpager for tablayout and inside a fragment of tablayout I am using recycler view I disable recyclerview nesterscrolling and want to scroll with nested scrollview but not working nothing scrolling. I check viewpager to set wrap_content and match_parent height but still not working not scrolling nesterdscrollview. Please guide me how to scroll nestedscrollview with viepager2 or viewpager

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/am_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:menu="@menu/top_menu" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/fm_scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/history_parent_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="@{history>0 ?View.VISIBLE :View.GONE}">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="History"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/fmv_clear_history"
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/fmv_historyRecyclerview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_video_history" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:baselineAligned="false"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/mainVideoTab"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:tabGravity="center"
                            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tabs_indicator"
                            app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="100"
                            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primaryColor"
                            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                            app:tabIndicatorHeight="20dp"
                            app:tabRippleColor="@null"
                            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/primaryColor"
                            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextStyle"
                            app:tabTextColor="@color/white">

                            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/video" />

                            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/folder" />
                        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                                android:id="@+id/fmv_sort_item"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                                android:rotation="90"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_swap"
                                android:visibility="@{tabPosition ==0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                                app:tint="@color/white"
                                tools:targetApi="m" />

                            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                                android:id="@+id/fmv_switchVideoView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_list"
                                android:visibility="@{tabPosition ==0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                                app:tint="@color/white"
                                tools:targetApi="m" />

                            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                                android:id="@+id/fmv_switchFolderView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_list"
                                android:visibility="@{tabPosition ==1 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                                app:tint="@color/white"
                                tools:targetApi="m" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                        android:id="@+id/mainVideoViewPager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mainVideoTab" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried by creating custom viepager2 to disable ontouchlistener and set touchlistener to nestedscrollview but still not worked and tyr to change height of viewpager to wrap_content and match_parent

Comment: In viepager2 make android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true". This will work.

Comment: @Vinay i tried not working app crashing